# Unicode Combining Diacritics across blocks

Tags: unicode

Is anyone aware of a way to add diacritics from different unicode blocks to say, latin letters (or latin diacritics to say, Devanagari letters)? For instance:

```
O&#x0948;
```

I tried the zero-width-joiner in between, but it had no effect. Any ideas?
I know, for instance, that the Arabic combining diacritics will work on latin letters, but Hebrew will not. Is this random?

Comment: I don't see _why_ something like this would be possible. Why would you want to add diacritics to a script that doesn't have them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accoding to the Unicode Standard, [Chapter 2](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/ch02.pdf), Section 2.11, “All combining characters can be applied to any base character and can, in principle, be used with any script.” So the Latin letter O followed by the Devanagari vowel sign ai U+0948 is permitted. But the standard adds: “This does not create an obligation on implementations to support all possible combinations equally well. Thus, while application of an Arabic annotation mark to a Han character or a Devanagari consonant is permitted, it is unlikely to be supported well in rendering or to make much sense.”

So it is up to implementations. But there are some “cross-script” diacritics. For example, the acute accent has been unified with the Greek tonos mark, so the Latin letter é and the Greek letter έ, when decomposed, contain the same diacritic U+0301. Moreover, this combining mark can be placed after a Cyrillic letter, and this can be regarded as normal (though relatively rare) usage, so we can expect good implementations to render it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine for me. I just typed in the characters. Probably depends on the program rendering the text.

Oै

[image]

Comment: What program did you use? It doesn't combine them in my browser (Chrome).